# use GetProcessImageFileName in mini filter driver

Tags: c, windows, minifilter

after using GetProcessImageFileName  function in mini filter driver , the driver failed to load with message

> "filter.sys cannot find KERNEL32.dll"

is there way to load kernel32.dll in mini filter ?

Comment: Why are you calling a user mode function?

Comment: cant find another way to get process name in  kernel mode and there is no strict requirement that GetProcessImageFileName cant be call in kernel mode in MSDN

Comment: Really. I thought you could not use use mode functions from kernel mode. But I'm no expert. I'm sure you are right.

Comment: You can't call Win32 API functions from the kernel.  If you can't find any other way to do what you want, launch a user-mode process to do it for you.

Answer (score -1):

little more investigation brings me to this [solution](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=472)

not exactly what i asked but worked for me